# Graph Theory: Question about union of 2 Paths

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Q: Prove that if a graph $G$ has $n \geq 2$ vertices, and the sum of the degrees of 2 different vertices is at least $n-2$ (for any 2 different vertices), then the graph has 2 disjoint simple paths, that their union builds the graph $G$ ('covers its vertices') . (The path can be of length $0$ meaning it contains only $1$ vertex)

I am so lost in this proof, I did not even know how to start, I guessed it is about trees, maybe I need to find 2 trees $T_1 ,T_2$ such that $T_1 \cup T_2 = G$ ? How does the information that $ \text{deg}_G(v) + \text{deg}_G(w) \geq  n-2 $ for each $v,w \in V(G) ~~ \text{and} ~~ v \neq w$ help us?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: The problems looks pretty close to a theorem related to graphs Hamiltonicity sufficient condition. You may want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem to see if it might be straightforward to modify the proof to solve your problem.

Comment: @YozefTjandra I know Ore's theorem but can't figure out how to use it here... :(

Comment: @StackOMeow Here's a suggestion of a plan : Start from some vertice, from there, try to build a path $P$ such that $G \setminus P$ satisfies Ore's theorem condition. Then $G \setminus P$ can be covered by a single path $P'$. Now $P$ and $P'$ are dijoint and $P \cup P' =G$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche But Ore's theorem is about hailtonian cycles, does it hold for here as well?

Comment: @StackOMeow The idea is to apply Ore's theorem to $G \setminus P$ : the theorem tells nyou that there is an Hamiltonian path for $G \setminus P$, i.e a simple path $P'$  that contains all vertices not in $P$ :)

Comment: I am still stuck on that proof... I would appreciate if you could help me to prove it just by giving me a headstart please! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add to $G$ two adjacent vertices, each adjacent to each vertex of $G$. Since the extended graph has $n+2\ge 4$ vertices and sums of degrees of any two of them is at least $n+2$, by [Ore’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) it has a Hamiltonian cycle. When we remove from it the added vertices, we obtain two (or even one) paths which span $G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this is fascinating! I have some questions: if we add 2 vertices that are joined to each other vertex with an edge, and we have given that the sum is at least $n-2$ , then how is it possible that after the addition the sum if $n +2$ ? isn't it supposed to be $n - 2 +  2 = n$ ? . One more question: Why when we remove from $G$ the added vertices we obtain 2 or 1 simple paths? if we remove them, the graph isn't hamiltonian anymore

Comment: @StackOMeow 1. If $v$ is any vertex of $G$ then when we add a vertex, adjacent to each vertex of $G$ (an so to $v$), we increase the degree of $v$ by one. 2. We remove the added vertices from the *cycle*, obtaining path(s).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks, you are correct, my bad :)